# Upload *all* photos into Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to create a backup photos app.
The app should upload all images into Firebase. When I start it the app uploads several photos perfectly but then crashes with this report.

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8@e245bda rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@e13b80b[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 0]

The code:

```
       StorageReference storage_photos=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();





private void tryToTakePhotos() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            try {
                final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
                final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
                //Stores all the images from the gallery in Cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                        null, orderBy);
                int count = cursor.getCount();
                int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                Toast.makeText(this, "dd" + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                storage_photos = storage_photos.child(name + "---" + count + "photos");


                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                    //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    StorageReference riversRef = storage_photos.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                    riversRef.putFile(uri);
                }
                cursor.close();
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                firebase_takePhotos.setValue("taken at: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
                        + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
                        + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));


            }catch (Exception e){
                firebase_takePhotos.setValue(""+e);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: you are getting that exception because for some reason there is 100 queued transactions? Are you somehow creating transactions in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this line in loop

```
StorageReference riversRef = storage_photos.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Because for every item in loop you are making a whole new reference , resulting a queue of 128 tasks. And when you put file it asynchronously uploads the file so you are making alot of async tasks.

Answer (score 0):

queued tasks = 128 indicates that you have reached maximum count of tasks 
implementation before kitkat can queue only 128 tasks. Above which it will issue RejectedExecutionException. So I would suggest you reduce the number of task created.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way to overcome this situation is by using `Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);` after the putFile call along with a counter variable.

Example:

```
private int fileCounter = 0;
private final int FILE_BATCH_COUNT = 50; //50 files
private final int TIME_REQUIRED_FOR_BATCH_UPLOAD = 5*60000; //5 min, varies according to your internet speed

//...

private void yourFunction(){
    //...
    fileCounter = fileCounter + 1;
    mStorageRef.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(...).addOnFailiureListener(...);

    if(fileCounter >= FILE_BATCH_COUNT){
        Thread.sleep(TIME_REQUIRED_FOR_BATCH_UPLOAD);
        fileCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

FILE_BATCH_COUNT : The number of files after which you have to pause the thread to wait for the upload to complete.

TIME_REQUIRED_FOR_BATCH_UPLOAD : You have to find out your upload time in milliseconds for the said amount of files. (considering all are of similar size. other improvise.)